# Do / while loop declaration and other errors

Tags: swift, loops, while-loop

I am having a problem trying to implement this basic do while loop.

I keep getting an error saying

> "statements are not allowed at the top level"

or another error (which highlights the word "do") saying

> "expected declaration"

I have checked the swift programming guide, and read through the relevant sections numerous times. I have also watched  every video I can find but just can not seem to figure out exactly what I am doing wrong.

here is the code.

```
//  loop.swift

import Foundation

var i = 17

do
{
   println("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16")
} while (i < 16)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is not your `main.swift` file (it appears to be your `loop.swift` file), you have to wrap your code in a function. You can call that function from `main.swift` or from other functions elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot Millie. When my reputation is above 15 ill be sure to come back here and vote up!

Comment: Thanks :). There's also accepting the answer. It actually gives more rep than an upvote and lets users know it provides a valid solution to the original question.